# Integrate birt in liferay portlet

Tags: jsp, liferay, birt, spring-portlet-mvc

I want to integrate Birt report 4.2.2 in my liferay 6.2 Portlet jsp page. All the document that i found talks about birt report 2.1 which the stucture is different from the 4.2.2 Any helps ?

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I follow to integrate Birt reports to my Php Applications.
Might be useful for you.
Assuming you have software necessary for birt environment

1. Put  JavaBridge.war file under tomcat/webapps directory and start tomcat service
2. After 10-20 seconds JavaBridge folder will be extracted there.
3. Stop tomcat service and delete JavaBridge.war file from there
4. Go to tomcat/webapps/JavaBridge/web-inf and locate lib directory
5. Rename lib to lib_old
6. Delete folder named “platform”
7. Now extract birt runtime if not extracted yet and go to ReportEngine and   locate lib folder
8. Copy lib folder and paste it to tomcat/webapps/JavaBridge/web-inf where your lib_old folder exists
9. Copy these jar files : birtEngine, JavaBridge, lucene, php-script, php-servlet, script-api from your lib_old folder and paste to lib folder
10. Delete lib_old folder and restart tomcat server